# RSpec NoMethodError: undefined method `assign'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec-rails, nomethoderror

I am trying to write tests for a small gem I have written for Rails. I want to test the gem independently of a dummy app and feel this is a good learning experience for me. However, I am stuck at getting a simple test to pass due to the above error.

My Gemfile points to the gemspec, I initialised RSpec with `rspec --init`.

My test (just to make sure everything is set up correctly before I begin in ernest):

```
RSpec.describe 'text_field', type: :view do
    it 'has something on the page' do
        assign(:users, [
          mock_model("User", id: 1, name: 'Ashley')
        ])
        stub_template 'users/_form.html.erb' => "<%= form_for @user do |f| %><%= f.text_field :name' %><% end %>"
        render
        rendered.should =~ /Ashley/
    end
end
```

The whole error:

```
text_field
  has something on the page (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) text_field has something on the page
     Failure/Error: assign(:users, [
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `assign' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TextField:0x007faa143e8828>
     # ./spec/tests/text_field_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.03812 seconds (files took 0.22166 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/tests/text_field_spec.rb:3 # text_field has something on the page

Top 1 slowest examples (0.03727 seconds, 97.8% of total time):
  text_field has something on the page
    0.03727 seconds ./spec/tests/text_field_spec.rb:3
```

My gemspec:

```
  ...
  spec.test_files    = Dir["spec/**/*.rb"]

  spec.required_ruby_version = "2.1.2"
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "1.6.3"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rails", "4.1.4"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails", "3.0.1"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec-activemodel-mocks", "1.0.1"
  ...
```

My spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'rspec/active_model/mocks'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  if config.files_to_run.one?
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  config.profile_examples = 10
  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.syntax = :expect
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.syntax = :expect
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

I have specified the test type as a view because my understaing of the RSpec docs is that assigns is only available in views. Have I missed an important step somewhere, or what am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I ran into this when upgrading to rspec(-rails) 3

Comment: No, not yet. It's still on my to complete list once I have a better grasp of both RSpec and Rails internals.

Comment: I apparently missed the `, type: :view` part which is think is new in rspec3, now mine is working...

Comment: Not sure about it, but look at this link, it may help
[This link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492578/rspec-1-3-3-rails-2-3-9-webrat-0-7-3-undefined-method-assign?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 6):

The answer, as Jarl says, is to put `type: view` somewhere in your testfile.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'search/print/_asset.html.haml', type: :view do
  it 'displays the page' do
    asset = build(:asset)
    render 'search/print/asset', asset: asset
    assert_select ":match('href', ?)", "/asset/#{asset.property_id}"
  end
end
```

You can be more selective about where you put it.  This also works: `it 'displays the page', type: view do ... end`

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo.  You used `assign`, but should have used `assigns`.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case and I have tried it. However, from the [docs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) it is `assign(key, val)` with an upgrade note `# rspec-rails-1.x assigns[key] = value # rspec-rails-2.x+ assign(key, value)`.

Comment: No, `assigns` is used to test expectations in controller specs.  `assign` is used to set assignments in view specs.